# "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a link in my rails layout template that has the following link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", "/login", class: "sign_in" %>
```

And the following js to hijack the click event:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){
      $('a.sign_in').on('click',function(e) {
        console.log("test");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

When I change the link to "login" (so without the slash) it works fine, and the click function executes. However, when I leave it as "/login" it gives me the error:

`"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg rails`

I am pulling my hair here... I googled for the error and found a lot of fixes for similar problems but neither seemed to work for me!

**EDIT: Issue has been SOLVED, it was related to an unrelated piece of code in application.js hijacking the same link**

Comment: I suspect you have an other callback somewhere bound on `a[href^="/login"]` on something. Is "msg rails" redacted or this is exactly how it appears ? This error fingerprint is typically a jquery error when you type a bad selector, like : `$('foo[bar<')`. You can look at stack trace in console to see where it happens, too.

Comment: This is the error as I see it in my console: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /login :checkbox

throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

And it happens in: 
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
 throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};

Comment: A bit deeper in the stack trace, maybe, that's the internal line that raises exception :) You have an other clue, though : something is trying to do `$('/login')`.

Comment: I only get this error when I actually click on the link - I will tail my log and see what happens

Comment: That's why it's probably from a other callback bound to your link. So, what does your stacktrace say about the error ?

Comment: Which stacktrace are you talking about? When I profile in firebug, I see that the last function called is: setupMatchPaths

Comment: What browser do you use ? In chrome/chromium, error displayed in console is provided with a clickable arrow on left which let you see the full callstack resulting in an error. This allows you to trace when error comes from.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37728/discussion-between-yossarian-and-olivier-el-mekki)

Answer (score 1):

In my case

> ```
> var splitId = "abcd/00001"; 
> $("#employeeChecked_"+splitId).val(chooseDate);
> ```

This code have displayed an error message

> ```
> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #employeeChecked_abcd/00001
>
> throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
> ```

Replaced it

> ```
> var splitId = "abcd/00001";
> var employeeChecked = "employeeChecked_"+splitId;
>     $("input[id='"+employeeChecked+"']").val(chooseDate);
> ```

// Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change

> console.log("test);

to

> console.log("test");

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", "/login", class: "sign_in" %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", "/login", :class => "sign_in" %>
```

OR to

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", login_path, :class => "sign_in" %>
```

It would work.

Comment: why you are calling e.preventDefault(); and return false; together?